# Using Min and Max to remove duplicate rows, and how to handle null values

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I am creating an SQL query in Oracle and I am trying to remove duplicate rows with a min and max aggregate function in a case statement. Here is the code at its current state:

```
select 
   Student_number,
       case 
       when min(sr.racecd) = max(sr.racecd) then min(sr.racecd) else 'Two or more races' 
   end as races
```

this is what the output looks like

```
Student Number   Race
4322             two or more races
4324             White
```

When I run the code it combines multiple rows into one and changes the name to 'two or more races'. But, the problem I am having is when it runs into a null value it changes it to 'Two or more races', too. How can I keep the Nulls as is, or change them to unknown? Also, when I add other columns in to the query the aggregate function does not work the same as when I am querying only studentnumber and racecd, why is that?

Comment: you can modify your case statement to include an additional condition that checks if the value is null using the IS NULL operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because NULL does not equal anything, so failing the equality test it goes to the THEN clause. There are a number of solutions. One is to use COUNT instead which ignores NULLs, like this:

```
select 
   Student_number,
       CASE WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT sr.raced) > 1) THEN 'Two or more races'
            ELSE MAX(sr.racecd)
       END
   end as races
```

As far as the issue with adding columns, when you add columns that are not aggregated you will be forced to include them in your GROUP BY. That changes the granularity of your query and the rows included in each group, so it will impact the result. If you want more information about student besides student_number, you'll want to aggregate other columns (e.g. with MAX() ).

Comment: That works perfectly, Thank you so much! How did you learn this? I have trouble finding resources for more advanced SQL. (If this is even considered advanced)